# Get specific parameters inside a json

Tags: php, json

I'm using PHP and
I Want to know how to get a specific parameter from a json array.

So here is my code:

```
$deviceList = $getdata->GetAll();
$json = json_decode($deviceList,true);
$json = (object)$json;
echo $json->imei;
```

However, i did not get any records from a parameter named imei.

Here is the json data:

```
{"id":"166","cellno":"639993370553","serialno":"0315212013915037","brand":"MeiTrack","model":"TC68S","imei":"867144020128490","description":"Personal Tracker","macaddress":"isjdioasjdioasn389257u238952","haulerid":"6","hauler":"Ronald","company_name":"Trial"},{"id":"165","cellno":"639993374250","serialno":"1234546789","brand":"MeiTrack","model":"MVT380","imei":"867965023790997","description":"32we4qweq","macaddress":"12343253","haulerid":"6","hauler":"Ronald","company_name":"Trial"},{"id":"164","cellno":"639433483172","serialno":"12345","brand":"O+","model":"O+ FAB GO","imei":"860799024505881","description":"Mobile","macaddress":"44:91:db:b8:16:78","haulerid":"5","hauler":"IOT Test","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"163","cellno":"639499333494","serialno":"43854320246","brand":"MEITRACK","model":"MVT-380","imei":"867965023803394","description":"TEST","macaddress":"f82t7g8","haulerid":"5","hauler":"IOT Test","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"162","cellno":"639499933495","serialno":"43854720788","brand":"MEITRACK","model":"MVT-380","imei":"867965026574638","description":"TEST","macaddress":"f82t7g8","haulerid":"5","hauler":"IOT Test","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"161","cellno":"639278921057","serialno":"42241020","brand":"meitrack","model":"t1","imei":"13777002439873","description":"test","macaddress":"f82t7g8","haulerid":"1","hauler":"Hauler #1","company_name":"IOT Technology Inc."},{"id":"160","cellno":"639499933495","serialno":"123456","brand":"meitrack","model":"t1","imei":"13949003229021","description":"test","macaddress":"f82t7g8","haulerid":"1","hauler":"Hauler #1","company_name":"IOT Technology Inc."},{"id":"159","cellno":"639771188829","serialno":"64327864237894","brand":"Test","model":"Test","imei":"74238974238744","description":"test","macaddress":"f82t7g8","haulerid":"1","hauler":"Hauler #1","company_name":"IOT Technology Inc."},{"id":"158","cellno":"639157181128","serialno":"234234234234","brand":"Test","model":"Test","imei":"423423423423423","description":"Test","macaddress":"23df23f32f32","haulerid":"1","hauler":"Hauler #1","company_name":"IOT Technology Inc."},{"id":"157","cellno":"639218109920","serialno":"67767867","brand":"Test","model":"Test","imei":"5763566763276867","description":"Test","macaddress":"678FT7HV79GJ","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"154","cellno":"639495904194","serialno":"89630315240272466798","brand":"V4S","model":"V4S","imei":"865747022735013","description":"Colpal - new APK","macaddress":"b8:98:f7:c0:b3:a8","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"146","cellno":"639495904213","serialno":"89630315240272466954","brand":"Gionee","model":"V4S","imei":"865747022747802","description":"Colpal - new APK","macaddress":"b8:98:f7:c1:22:2f","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"145","cellno":"639981600078","serialno":"356707070404363","brand":"SAMSUNG","model":"SM-J105B","imei":"356707070404363","description":"UCM DEVICE","macaddress":"2C:AE:2B:5D:85:08","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"144","cellno":"639495904526","serialno":"89630315240272469354","brand":"V4S","model":"V4S","imei":"865747022700819","description":"MYA device (already changed the APK & URL)","macaddress":"b8:98:f7:bc:91:40","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"143","cellno":"639495904527","serialno":"89630315240272469362","brand":"GIONEE","model":"V4S","imei":"865747022762850","description":"Mya Device (Already updated APK & URL)","macaddress":"b8:98:f7:c0:7c:b0","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"139","cellno":"639495904175","serialno":"865747022780076","brand":"Gionee","model":"V4S","imei":"865747022780076","description":"Colpal","macaddress":"b8:98:f7:c0:2a:1a","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"},{"id":"137","cellno":"639214185416","serialno":"89630315225170455191","brand":"MyPhonemy81","model":"MyPhone_my81","imei":"359530070027704","description":"FMM Device","macaddress":"64:21:40:92:db:16","haulerid":"3","hauler":"IOT Hauler","company_name":"Test Company2"}]
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: If you want an object, leave the `true` parameter off the `json_decode()`

Comment: Hi! Already removed the true in json decode.Still can't get the imei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a json datastructure denoting an array of objects, so you have to process it or address it as such.

```
$deviceList = $getdata->GetAll();
$json = json_decode($deviceList);
foreach ( $json as $obj ) {
    echo $obj->id . ' = ' . $obj->imei . '<br>';
}
```

Output =

```
166 = 867144020128490
165 = 867965023790997
164 = 860799024505881
163 = 867965023803394
162 = 867965026574638
161 = 13777002439873
160 = 13949003229021
159 = 74238974238744
158 = 423423423423423
157 = 5763566763276867
154 = 865747022735013
146 = 865747022747802
145 = 356707070404363
144 = 865747022700819
143 = 865747022762850
139 = 865747022780076
137 = 359530070027704
```